# How to get the the values of a vtkDoubleArray in a std::vector

Tags: c++, vtk

I want to copy the elements of a `vtkDoubleArray` into a C++ `std::vector` (as in [How to convert a vtkDoubleArray to an Eigen::matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651271/how-to-convert-a-vtkdoublearray-to-an-eigenmatrix))

I am trying to get this to work:

```
typedef std::vector<double> row_type;
typedef std::vector<row_type> matrix_type;

int n_components = vtk_arr->GetNumberOfComponents();
int n_rows = vtk_arr->GetNumberOfTuples();

row_type curTuple(n_components);
matrix_type cpp_matrix(n_rows, row_type(n_components));
for (int i=0; i<n_rows; i++) {
    vtk_arr->GetTuple(i, curTuple);
    cpp_matrix[i] = curTuple;
}
```

At the moment I have this error:

```
error C2664: 'void vtkDataArrayTemplate<T>::GetTuple(vtkIdType,double
*)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'row_type' to 'double *'
```

Is there some `vtk` method (hopefully, more robust and efficient) which already achieves this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the errors says, you are passing a `row_type` (`std::vector<double>`) where it expects a `double*`. Perhaps you want to pass a pointer to the underlying data:

```
vtk_arr->GetTuple(i, curTuple.data());
```

See [`std::vector::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) for more info.