# How to convert a vtkDoubleArray to an Eigen::matrix

Tags: c++, vtk, eigen

I've found the Eigen::Map class for converting a raw array to an Eigen class (and some useful snippets here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12007784/1136458 )

Is there any Eigen or vtk class to convert a vtk array to an Eigen class (and back)?
What I am trying right now is:

- convert vtkDoubleArray to std::vector of std::vector (as in  [How to get the the values of a vtkDoubleArray in a std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650468/how-to-get-the-the-values-of-a-vtkdoublearray-in-a-stdvector) )
- using map to have a matrixxd

  ```
  Eigen::MatrixXd eig_arr; 
  eig_arr = Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> (cpp_matrix.data(), n_rows, n_components)
  ```

But I get the following error:

error C2665: 'Eigen::Map::Map' : none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types

I don't necessarily need the intermediate cpp_matrix, if there is a direct method that would be fine as well

Comment: You write `curTuple` from `vtk_arr->GetTuple(i, curTuple)` component-wise to `cpp_matrix` [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650468/how-to-get-the-the-values-of-a-vtkdoublearray-in-a-stdvector#24650468). Why dont you write it directly component-wise into the `Eigen::Matrix`?

Comment: I just started this way because I hoped that there existed some method in vtk like GetRawArray, so that I could do: eig_arr = map(vtk_arr->getRawData). But yes, since I have already implemented how to scan the vtkarray I can just adapt that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory layout of a `std::vector<std::vector<double> >` is not compatible with what `Eigen::Map` is expecting. All entries must be sequentially stored in memory with an optional constant space between each column. So if the memory layout of `vtkDoubleArray` is not comptable, then you have no other choice but copy the values using a manual for loop.

Answer (score 0):

What about converting vtkMappedDataArray to Eigen::matrix?

I stumpled upon "vtkMappedDataArray" and this discussion about "[InSituDataStructures](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/InSituDataStructures)" for VTK.
Unfortunatly I don't know any details but maybe it helps. Please let us know.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this! At a first glance it seems the  use of vtkmappedarray is opposite to mine: it should map external data in a vtkarray.  But I found an interesting reference to the getvoidpointer method , I could try that or getvoidpointer.